# matplotlib pyplot.plt.style works in Terminal, but not in SublimeText, PyCharm, or BBEdit

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm having a lot of trouble with matplotlib, specifically `pyplot.style.use()`. What I have.

First, some sample code, adapted from Python Crash Course 2e.

```py
inputvalues = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
squares = [1, 4, 9, 16, 25]
plt.style.use('seaborn')
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter (2, 4, s=200)
plt.show()
```

When entered one line at the time on the python terminal, everything works as expected. However, when run through any of my Python editors, I get errors.

In Sublime Text, the `plt.style.use('seaborn')` is flagged and the console says

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<file path>", line 6, in <module>
    plt.style.use('seaborn')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'style'
```

In Pycharm, the error seems more fundamental. It triggers on the very first line of the script saying

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<filepath>", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

BBedit has a similar but distinct matplotlib error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<file path>", line 3, in <module>
    plt.style.use('seaborn')
NameError: name 'plt' is not defined
```

This variety of errors is beyond my n00b python powers to debug.

Comment: i get similar errors when I try to run the line 
```from sympy import Symbol, pprint, init_printing```
from another script.

I thought there might be a matplotlib error, but I installed matplotlib again using pip and the errors persist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably running different python environments without meaning to. One environment is activated in the terminal - that one has `matplotlib` installed. Another one is used in PyCharm - that one doesn't.

So the root cause isn't about Python coding, it's about getting each app to point to the same python executable. Compare the executable path in your PyCharm config at `Preferences | Project | Project Interpreter` with the one you have in Terminal. The Python executable set for Terminal can be found by running `` echo `which python` ``.

Comment: Looks like you’re onto something. Terminal is pointing to ~/anaconda3/bin/python and PyCharm is pointing to ~/PyCharmProjects/test/venv/bin/python. 

I somehow thought OS X had a default system Python that everything used, maybe at /use/local/bon/Python3.7. What’s your opinion on where I should point my various editors to? The anaconda implementation or the (maybe nonexistent) system default one?

Comment: it depends on what python environment you want for your project, which i can't decide for you. judging by the PyCharm path, you have the `pyenv` package installed on your machine as well, which adds additional complexity. i'd suggest picking an env - any env that you think might work - and making all your apps use it first. then you can worry about exactly how the env is configured, probably in a separate SO question